# on change event of text area add text using fabric.js on canvas

Tags: jquery, html, css, fabricjs

on change event of text area i am adding text on canvas how can i set final text on canvas using the following code  i am getting many string .

[image]

```
   $('#filedset').delegate(' textarea', 'change keyup', function() {

        console.log('text area change');
        var message = $(this).val();
 var text1 = new fabric.Text(message, { left: 100, top: 100 });
 canvas.add(text1);
    });
    $('#change_pos').click(function ()
    {
        console.log('button clicked');
        rect.set({ left: 120, top: 150 });
        canvas.renderAll();
    });
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the question -- If you don't want multiple texts, why do you create a new one on each `keyup`?

Comment: @xec thanks i dint realise that i have added keyup also .

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a little old but I thought I would try to help out since I had to solve the exact thing.

```
// Your Fabric Canvas
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('YOURCANVASID');

// New event handler to take the value from the textarea and send to the addText utility function. 
$('.add-text').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = $('#filedset').val();
    addText(text);
});

// Watches the keyup event handler in your textarea and updates the selected text node on canvas while you are typing. Creates a nice effect. 
// with whats being typed. 

 $('#filedset').on('keyup' , function(){

    var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();

     // We do a check to make sure there is an active canvas object, and see if it's text. 
    if (activeObject && activeObject.type === 'text') {
        if (!this.value) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            activeObject.setText(this.value);
            console.log(this.value);
        }
    }

    canvas.renderAll();

});

// Function to add the text, just pass in a text string you want to add to the canvas. 
function addText(addtext) {
    var text = new fabric.Text(addtext, {  });
    canvas.add(text);
    // Center The New Text on the canvas or position it wherever
    canvas.centerObject(text);
}
```

This is untested in its current form as it comes from a larger, namespaced application i wrote. But it should work. You were heading in the right direction but you where essentially adding a new text node on keyup / change. I hope this helps someone.